# Measure Theory and Law of Large numbers

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, law-of-large-numbers

If $X_1,X_2,...$ are non-negative random variables with the same distribution (but the variables are not necessarily independent) and $E[X_1]< \infty $, prove that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}E\left[\max_{ i< n}\frac{X_i}{n}\right]=0.$$

This is what I have so far

Xi     = √n+(Xi −√n)

```
   ≤√n+(Xi −√n)+(=max)
```

maxi< n  Xi ≤ √n +(=max)

maxi< n(Xi − √n)+(=max)

```
   ≤√n + sigma from i<n of (Xi −√n)+(=max)
```

how do I finish this to establish the desired result

Comment: This is what I have so far
Xi  =√n+(Xi −√n) 
    ≤√n+(Xi −√n)+
maxi<n Xi ≤ √n + maxi<n(Xi − √n)+
    ≤√n+sigma from i<n of (Xi −√n)+
how do I finish this to establish the desired result

Answer (score 2):

Let $M_n=\max\{X_i\mid i\leqslant n\}$ and $u_n(x)=\frac1nP(M_n\geqslant x)$ then
$$\frac{E[M_n]}n=\int_0^\infty u_n(x)\mathrm dx.$$
Note that  $u_n\to0$ pointwise since $u_n\leqslant\frac1n$ uniformly and that, for every $x$, $[M_n\geqslant x]\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i\leqslant n}[X_i\geqslant x]$ hence $P(M_n\geqslant x)\leqslant nP(X_1\geqslant x)$, that is, $u_n\leqslant u_1$.

Since $u_1$ is integrable, Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem then shows that 
$$\int_0^\infty u_n(x)\mathrm dx\to0.$$